# Is $\frac {x^4 +2y^2}{(x^2 +y^2)^{\lambda}}$ totally differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\lambda$ be a positive real number.
 When is the function
$$f(x,y) ＝ \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }(x, y) = (0, 0) \\
\dfrac{x^4 +2y^2}{(x^2 +y^2)^{\lambda}} &\text{if } (x, y) \neq (0, 0)\end{cases}$$
totally differentiable?

Find all $\lambda$ where f is totally differentiable.

This is a question from exam of Tokyo university.

https://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/kyoumu/a20170524.pdf
question No3（2）

I think there is no easy necessary and sufficient condition in this problem, so I tired to find some necessary conditions （and check that is sufficient）but I couldn't find it .

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far! Have you for example tried to analyse when $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$?

Comment: By using polar coordinates, x＝rcosθ, y＝rsinθ, I think r＜１　is the condition where f is continuous at （0,0）.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take limit with different cases

$$y= 0$$$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^4}{x^{2\lambda}}$$

This limit is equal to 0 when $\lambda<2$

Take another case $ x=0$

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{2y^2}{y^{2\lambda}}$$

Now here the limit goes to zero when $$\lambda<1$$

So we can summarise that when $$\lambda <1$$.We took $\lambda<1$ because in this range both cases limit to 0 but after $\lambda>1$ limit x goes to zero but y doesn't

Comment: I think your conclusion is right, but maybe it would be more rigorous to transform into polar coordinates and then let r go to zero. Also, one argument is missing: Why does being continuous (what you prove) imply being totally differentiable? I would argue that is because, then the function is simply a combination of polynomials, which we know to be differentiable.

Comment: what about $f(x) = |x|$? continuous everywhere, but not differentiable at 0.